# Determine (up to a constant multiplier) the polynomial with a maximum at (-1,1), a minimum (1,-1) and no other critical points

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Q:Determine (up to a constant multiplier) the polynomial with a maximum at (-1,1), a minimum (1,-1) and no other critical points

It would be great if someone could show how this is determined. My initial thoughts are it would be in the form of  $x^3 + x^2 + x + c$ but how do we determine the exact form.

Thanks!

Comment: You have four pieces of information (the value of the derivative at two points, and the value of the function at two points) with which you need to find the four coefficients of $a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$. I bet you could come up with a system of linear equations to solve, if nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $f(x) = ax^{3} + bx^{2} + cx + d$. Since you want this polynomial to have critical points at $x = \pm 1$, we require that $f'(\pm 1) = 0$. This yields the two equations
\begin{align*}
3a + 2b + c & = 0\\
3a - 2b + c & = 0.
\end{align*}
It is then obvious that $b = 0$ and $c = -3a$. From here, one can obtain another two equations from the requirements that $f(1) = -1$ and $f(-1) = 1$. It is a simple matter to solve for $a$ and $d$.

Also note that this is the only such polynomial with degree at most 3. Also, there are no such functions with degree less than $3$. To see this, we observe that the derivative in this case will have degree at most $2$. Since it must, by assumption, have at least two distinct critical points at $\pm 1$, this forces $f'(x)$ to have degree $2$

However, if we allow for higher degree polynomials, then there may be infinitely many solutions since the critical points at $\pm 1$ may have arbitrary orders (i.e. they could be degenerate). By the condition on the critical points of $f$, we have the general formula
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) = a_{n,k}(x-1)^{k}(x+1)^{n}, \quad 1 \leq n,k
\end{equation*}
and $a_{n,k}$ is a constant to be determined by the constraints
\begin{equation*}
f(1) = -1, \quad f(-1) = 1.
\end{equation*}

By the fundamental theorem of Calculus, we can then write
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \int_{-1}^{x}a_{n,k}(t-1)^{k}(t+1)^{n}\,dt + f(-1) = \int_{-1}^{x}a_{n,k}(t-1)^{k}(t+1)^{n}\,dt + 1.
\end{equation*}
Then we can determine $a_{n,k}$ from the equation
\begin{equation*}
-1 = f(1) = \int_{-1}^{1}a_{n,k}(t-1)^{k}(t+1)^{n}\,dt + 1.
\end{equation*}
Making the substitution $u = t+1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
-2 = \int_{0}^{2}a_{n,k}(u-2)^{k}u^{n}\,du.
\end{equation*}

Now integrate by parts $k$ times to get rid of the $(u-2)^{k}$ factor, and we have
\begin{equation*}
-2 = a_{n,k}\left[ \frac{k!n!}{(n+k+1)!}(-1)^{k}u^{n+k+1}\right]_{u=0}^{2} = a_{n,k} \frac{k!n!}{(n+k+1)!}(-1)^{k}2^{n+k+1}.
\end{equation*}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
a_{n,k} = \frac{(n+k+1)!(-1)^{k+1}}{n!k!2^{n+k}}.
\end{equation*}

So we seek polynomials of the form
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \frac{(n+k+1)!(-1)^{k+1}}{n!k!2^{n+k}} \int_{-1}^{x}(t-1)^{k}(t+1)^{n}\,dt + 1, \quad n, k \geq 1.
\end{equation*}
However, there is one last thing that we must check, which is to ensure that such $f$ don't have possible saddle points at $x = \pm 1$. For this, we use the constraints
\begin{align*}
f'(x) > 0 & \quad \textrm{ for } x < -1\\
f'(x) < 0 & \quad \textrm{ for } x > 1.
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{sign}(f'(x)) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{sign}(a_{n,k})(-1)^{k}(-1)^{n} & x < -1\\
\mathrm{sign}(a_{n,k})(-1)^{k} & -1 < x < 1\\
\mathrm{sign}(a_{n,k}) & 1 < x
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
From this we deduce that $a_{n,k} > 0$ and that $n,k$ are both odd. Also note that $a_{n,k} > 0$ whenever $k$ is odd so we just need the second condition. So, all solutions to the problem have the form
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \frac{(n+k+1)!(-1)^{k+1}}{n!k!2^{n+k}} \int_{-1}^{x}(t-1)^{k}(t+1)^{n}\,dt + 1, \quad n, k \geq 1, \quad n,k \textrm{ odd }.
\end{equation*}

Comment: And I assume there's no other polynomial that satisfies this?

Comment: Correction, the polynomial you obtain as described above, which turns out to be $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x(x^{2} - 3)$ is the only such polynomial with degree at most $3$. If we allow for higher degree polynomials, than there can possibly be infinitely many solutions. I will edit the above post to generalize this.

Comment: If "critical points" refers only to real critical points, there are lots of other solutions.
For example, $(x^5 - 5 x)/4$.

Comment: Points do only refer to real critical points @RobertIsrael